# Resizing XAML designer for Windows Store app to preview different screen sizes

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'd like to preview how my app page will look with some different screen widths (full screen and several narrow layouts) in Visual Studio XAML designer. At this moment it's laid out as if for the full screen.

Is there a way to preview the page for different widths in Visual Studio?

Comment: You could set your design widths/heights by specifying `d:DesignWidth` & `d:DesignHeight` up with your namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Device tool window available from the Design menu that has a list of different standard devices as well as orientation and other settings that can affect the display of your app. The same is available in Blend.